# Flow Pause Component with 0 Hour Delay

Tags: visual-workflow

I have found that setting a Pause with a 0 hour delay results in a about a 1 minute delay. Does anyone know is this is a valid and reliable setting?  If it is, I would use it.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not valid or reliable in the sense that it's not a documented way of using this feature.

Having said that, we use it in a few places. Importantly, it means that whatever actions take place after the Pause will be a new transaction, which can be helpful in certain cases. In my experience, the same principle applies to Time-Based Workflows and Scheduled Actions in process builder.

This link gives some context:
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000id1dQAA

Here is another way of implementing this:
https://sftipshack.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/the-5-minute-time-based-workflow-or-15-minute-or-30-minute/

Comment: That's for the feedback Ben.